# find hex string in input read python3 in mac works, in ubuntu fails

Tags: python, string

I have the following data in the first 48 bytes of a file: (hex):

FF D8 FF E1 3F B1 45 78 69 66 00 00 4D 4D 00 2A 00

00 00 08 00 0B 01 0E 00 02 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 92

01 0F 00 02 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 9A 01 10 00 02 00

Then I read them in and try to locate the string 4D 4D 00 2A

('Exif' is the string: 45 78 69 66)

```
fn.seek(0,0)
first_32_byte=str(fn.read(34))
print(first_32_byte)
print(first_32_byte.upper())
if (first_32_byte.upper().find('EXIF') >= 0) :
    print('EXIF Found')
    tiff_hdr=first_32_byte.find('\x4D\x4D\x00\x2A')
    print(' tiff_hdr=',tiff_hdr)
```

the string 'Exif' is found correctly.

On UBUNTU python3 I get that the tiff_hdr = -1  (i.e.  string not found)

On Mac python 3 I get that tiff_hdr = 12 (decimal)

How can that be ????

Comment: can you try the same but using bytes objects?

Comment: @Marat:  changing '\x4D\x4D\x00\x2A'  to str(B'\x4D\x4D\x00\x2A') does not change the result.  Also when I put in 'MM\x00*' it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Apparently this version of Ubuntu python3 (3.8.10 - Sept. 28 2021) has tightened the type checking between strings and bytes. By taking away the str re-typing from the file read, first_32_bytes becomes a byte object. When looking for the string 'Exif' a re-type to str is necessary and by making the search string when searching for x4D4D002A also a byte object this all works again. pffftt...